# Bypass Censorship and Filtering Using Blockchain Technology

Tags: network, censorship, filtering, blockchain

I heard some people and companies (like [Telegram](https://telegram.me)) claiming it's possible to bypass censorship & filtering of internet using Blockchain technology, for example to prevent censorship of a certain messenger application.

Please take a look at this [twit](https://twitter.com/durov/status/947420374102413312?lang=en) by CEO of Telegram:

> Public group chats on Telegram are encrypted and inaccessible for
>   governments. As for blockchain-based anticensorship tools: we are
>   working on them, will announce in Q1 2018.

I want to know is it possible at all? If yes, how exactly it may work?

Comment: PKI already resolve the exposed data issue. Why reinvent the wheel with cumbersome ledger and unwanted computing?  Whoever that "blockchain" everything must have a big incentive in electricity company stock.

Answer (score 4):

Blockchain is essentially an information storage which is resistant against manipulation, i.e. modifying of information or deleting information. Given that a blockchain can and is usually replicated to many places it is hard to block access to it without causing serious collateral damage like [blocking large parts of the internet](https://www.theverge.com/2018/4/17/17246150/telegram-russia-ban).

Thus, blockchain could in theory to be used to spread information, bypassing censorship. This could be public information. But it could also private information addressed only at selected recipients by encrypting these information with public keys where the private keys are only known to the specific recipients.

But of course, blockchain could not only be used by good guys to publish true information where access to these information is actively denied by the bad guys. Similarly it could be used to spread false information which might look like true information, i.e. the kind of information the good guys would like to suppress because they consider them false but cannot suppress anymore due to blockchain. This way the recipients can be drowned in lots of different information so that they don't really know what is true and whom to trust.  [We can see this kind of "information warfare" today](https://slate.com/technology/2018/01/twitter-admits-there-were-more-than-50-000-russian-bots-confusing-u-s-voters-in-2016.html) and it is actually a pretty old method.

In other words: blockchain could be used to bypass direct censorship which denies access to information. But as can be seen a lot already today another way to suppress unwanted information is the spread of false information and also actively undermining the trust into specific "good" guys. Insofar I'm skeptical that blockchain will really solve the problem of censorship. But it might cause a shift in the ways censorship is done.

Comment: There's a funny anecdote about the blockchain's immutability. I can't find the article on it, but some big wig in the federal finance department (Fed Reserve or something similar)'s face has been added to the blockchain and can never be removed. It was added as a prank because of the animosity between cryptocurrency enthusiasts and 'traditional' banks, the Fed, etc. I'm sure someone reading this will immediately know what I'm talking about and can link it.